# How to add multiple attributes in BeatifulSoup to get html element?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For web scraping with BeautifulSoup, I want to get the second span value "Tk 2,050".

**html**

```
<p class="book-price"> 
<strike class="original-price pl-2">TK. 2,300</strike> 
<span>TK. 2,050</span> </p>
```

I have tried the below code.

```
prices = soup.find("p",class_ ="book-price")
```

It returns "TK. 2,300 TK. 2,050"

I only want the span value. How can I implement it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS selector with `select_one`.

```py
prices = soup.select_one('p.book-price > span')
print(prices.text)
```

Alternatively, you can chain `find` calls.

```py
prices = soup.find("p", class_="book-price").find('span')
```